# pow() gives unexpected result when using typecasting

Tags: c++

when I write code as

```
int  m=4;
print(pow(10,m/2))
```

it gives me result 100.

But when I do

```
int  m=4;
print((int)pow(10,m/2))
```

It gives result 99.

Can anyone suggest why this is happening?

Comment: what is the print function in C++ ?

Comment: i just wrote it as print. i wrote as cout<<pow(10,m/2)<<endl; in my prog.

Comment: Assuming print works like printf and doesn't do anything weird... well I can't replicate your results. [See here](https://ideone.com/gCqPuk)

Comment: http://ideone.com/4rn0iZ

Comment: Works perfect for me.. I don't like this `print` you have there...

Comment: i haven't tried it on ideone . i am using dev c++

Comment: well it's working perfact on ideone :)

Comment: `i am using dev c++`. Switch. NOW!

Comment: No problem with gcc. Change compiler

Comment: "i just wrote it as print. i wrote as `cout<<pow(10,m/2)<<endl;` in my prog": Show the complete, actual, compilable code please.

Answer (score 5):

**EDIT:**

It's a bug of dev C++ compiler.

ADVICE: don't use dev C++ any more, it's really too old.

Comment: Not only is it old, it also never left beta stage.

Comment: Dev c++ is an IDE - it might be using any number of compilers. But it does look like the newest package has a very old MinGW - 3.4.2.